# How can I call a Javascript function in python?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, electron

I'm trying to make a snake game with Electron and deep reinforcement learning. The reinforcement learning stuff I do in python and the game in Javascript. Now how can I call a function like this in python?

```
makeSomeThing(x) {

}
```

or

```
getValue() {
   return x;
}
```

Comment: What framework are you using to connect Python with Electron?

Comment: None, I don't have any idea how to combine those.

Comment: use `pyexecjs` module to call a function in js file.

Comment: Actually I just need to "send" data between js and py and I think it's the easiest way when I store my data in a file and than read it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Please build your python script to an executable binary file. You can use [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) to package your python scripts to a standalone executable file.
2. Then you can spawn this binary file at your Electron project like this.

   ```
   import { spawn } from 'child_process';
   // in my case I'm storing the file at bin directory at the root path of the application
   // You can change this whatever you want

   const pythonPath = const basicURL = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
   ? path.join(__dirname, './bin/xxxx')
   : path.join(process.resourcesPath, 'bin', 'xxxx');

   const params = ['arg1', 'arg2'];  // params that your python scripts need.
   const pythonChildProcess = spawn(pythonPath, params);
     pythonChildProcess.stdout.on('data', data => {
       console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);

       // Here is where the output goes
     });
     pythonChildProcess.stderr.on('data', data => {
       console.log(`tderr: ${data}`);

       // Here is where the error output goes
     });
     pythonChildProcess.on('close', code => {
       console.log(`closing code: ${code}`);
       // Here you can get the exit code of the script
     });
   ```

Comment: thank you tpikachu but  I'd like to call a Javascript function in python.

Comment: @GianLaager not a normal way. But I thought as you are going to run python script at Electron app

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know if it is the answer that you expect, but I would create a standalone python service that exposes some API.

Create a client in electron and use python API to send data and get processed information from the Python service

You cant call Javascript API from python. You need something in the middle anyway.